# General questions about the telephone line a.k.a "last mile"

Tags: transmission-line, digital-communications, telephone, signal-theory

Before the digital data gets conveyed over the "last mile", it passes a modem, which converts this digital data into audio signals (Which is often called analog) (but the binary system still is there, as audio signals represent 1 and 0 (high tone = 1, low tone = 0) as the "last mile" is only able to convey this type of signal (namly audio).

But isn't the telephone line as copper as an ethernet cable (if you know what I mean)? Why can this telephone line only convey audio signals?

And how is the audio-signal conveyed over this copper cable? (I don't think it will convey my voice when I speak into the cable...).

Are many audio signals transmitted over the "last mile", so does it even matter if they interfere (As I think that when using DSL over 40000 audio signals must be transmitted in one second (40kHz frequency sometimes))!?

Comment: 1. no, it's not like "the binary system is still there" the way you describe it; modern PTOS modems don't do a 2-FSK (two tones). 2. No, I don't know what you mean, please describe what you mean. 3. have you researched "Telephone", maybe by reading the wikipedia article? 4. Um "40000 audio signals are transmitted": this doesn't make sense and isn't true, either.

Comment: `audio-signal conveyed over this copper cable` .... audio signal is not transmitted over copper .... electrical representation of an audio signal is transmitted over copper

Comment: @jsotola voltage?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah... I'd better read some articles...

Comment: @watchme "voltage?": that is a single word, and a single word with a question mark doesn't constitute a question one can answer? All in all, I find it very hard to find the things in your post that aren't based on a pure misunderstanding. So, maybe, could you focus on *one* question, and remove the others

Comment: modems no longer use high/low tones to represent `1 and 0` ... the signal that is exchanged between modems is very much more complex

Comment: @watchme, `voltage?` .... no .... electrical current is transmitted

Comment: @watchme, please do some research on the internet .... for instance, find out the maximum length of an ethernet cable between devices (computers, switches, etc) .... you will find that it is much shorter than you think

Comment: @jsotola oh you mean, they CAN convey the same signal, but they don't as the distance "requires" another format of how the information is carried.

Comment: @watchme I spent some time studying math papers on HDSL and ADSL and IDSL. They use many narrow frequency bands and constantly monitor and adapt to the complex impedances at each. That was "back in the day." Stuff has changed since then. I just had my fiber unit replaced about a month ago and while the technicians were here, I asked them about what's "going on with copper" these days. They said that with a dual pair of standard twisted copper they are just rolling out 30M bps over copper. I don't know how that's done. But it kind of shocked me.

Comment: @jonk, i have an internet connection over copper .... www.speedtest.net reports 29.5 Mbps download 6.15 Mbps upload .... it is truly freaky .... i remember 600 baud clearly ... lol

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the confirmation!! It was just word from them, before now. It's good to hear some confirmation. Is your case also using two twisted-pairs?

Answer (score 4):

> But isn't the telephone line as copper as an ethernet cable (if you
>   know what I mean)? Why can this telephone line only convey audio
>   signals?

Telephone lines can convey multiple signals at the same time, how fast is a matter of bandwidth.

[image]
Source: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Networks/DSL

If you look above the voice part of the phone line goes from 0 to 4kHz, you can't transmit signals faster than 4kHz, which is about where your data rate is. If you use the full 25kHz with a modem and some comm tricks you can get 56kbps with a normal analog modem.

DSL uses higher frequency, and more bandwidth to get a higher data rate.

So no, the last mile problem will not be solved with 'audio' signals

Read up on [Comm theory](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Networks/DSL) to understand the relation between data rate and bandwidth of the comm channel

Comment: oh therefore Upstream will never be as fast es Downstream...

Comment: Yeah, but thats for ADSL

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing various systems. It appears that in this question you are asking about the conversion of digital telephone data signals to analog for the "last mile" to the subscriber's phone.

> Before the digital data gets conveyed over the "last mile", it passes a modem, which converts this digital data into audio signals (Which is often called analog) (but the binary system still is there, as audio signals represent 1 and 0 (high tone = 1, low tone = 0) as the "last mile" is only able to convey this type of signal (namly audio).

No. The digital audio signal is converted to analogue using a DAC (digital to analogue converter). After conversion the digital data is no longer there; it is 100% analogue.

> But isn't the telephone line as copper as an ethernet cable (if you know what I mean)? Why can this telephone line only convey audio signals?

The telephone line actually carries about 50 V DC (to power the phone, detect on/off hook and for dialling pulses), about 90 V AC (to ring the bell) and signal of up to around 1 V AC (for speech).

> And how is the audio-signal conveyed over this copper cable? (I don't think it will convey my voice when I speak into the cable...).

Microphones convert varying air-pressure signals (your voice) into varying voltage signals which are transmitted over wires. Earpieces convert varying voltage signals into varying air-pressure signals. These signals are analogous to (like) each other in that one varies in proportion to the other, hence "analogue".

> Are many audio signals transmitted over the "last mile", so does it even matter if they interfere.

Each subscriber has a dedicated pair of wires. There is no interference.

> (As I think that when using DSL over 40000 audio signals must be transmitted in one second (40kHz frequency sometimes))!?

40 kHz is one signal oscillating at 40,000 times per second. It is not 40,000 signals.

Comment: Good. Please wait a day or two to give others a chance to answer and then accept an answer on each of your questions if your question has been addressed to your satisfaction. You can also upvote one or more answers that are useful.